# why dropdown value when window.history.back() is lost

Tags: php, jquery

I have code html and using jquery to manage cascade dropdown
as dropdown1 is selected the value is dropdown2 will change.

after submit I have validate some fields if its blank i will call window.history.back()
that is ok value in first name box or dropdown1 is still maintain value that I input and I can continue to input another fields continue do not reinput those fields all.

but why value in dropdown2 is lost how to keep and display the value before submit
[form input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYH1j.png)

here is step to reproduce

1. input first name, select dropdown1, dropdown2 has select value
   2 click add ,  in this step i have validate other dropdown must has value
   3 alert message and window.history.back
   4 value at dropdown2 is lost

[dropdown2 value lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzWO4.png)

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#dropdown2").change(function() {
                $("#dropdown3").empty();
                $("#dropdown3").append(`<option value="A">choice a</option>`);
                $("#dropdown3").append(`<option value="B">choice b</option>`);
          });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
    First name
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>   <br>
    Dropdown1
    <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">choice 1</option>
    <option value="2">choice 2</option>
    </select>
    Dropdown2
    <select name="dropdown3" id="dropdown3">
    </select> <br>       <br>
    Other Dropdown
    <select name="other_dropdown" id="other_dropdown">
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">choice 1</option>
    <option value="2">choice 2</option>
    </select> <br>      <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Add</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because your dropdown3 value got changed when you select something in dropdown2 and since it's added via ajax code, it will not remain there, as page got refreshed and original form HTML for drop-down 3 will render

Comment: Going "back" doesn't automatically *restore* the page to exactly how it was.